# Can someone help me run a CSS animation after a keypress?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I've been trying to get an animation to display when I press the Konami code and while I've managed to get an alert window to open (which pops up 3 to 5 times in a row, for some reason), I cannot get the animation to appear.

Here is my CSS Code:

```
#pirateship {
    position:absolute; top:420px;width:100%;
    height:160px;
    background-image:url(pirateship.png);
    background-position:-200px;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
.sail {
    animation: sailing 8s infinite linear;
}
```

Here is my Script:

```
if (window.addEventListener) {var state=0, Konami=[38,38,40,40,37,39,37,39,66,65];
window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
if (e.keyCode==Konami[state]) state++; else state=0; if (state==10)
$('#pirateship').addClass('sail'); window.alert("test");}, true);}
```

And of course, I just display this in the body:

```
<div id="pirateship" ></div>
```

In other words, the portion that doesn't work is this part:

```
$('#pirateship').addClass('sail');
```

I've tried it several different ways, based on people's recommendations here and similar sites, without success.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: It's working fine, but you haven't defined `@keyframes sailing {}` http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRpoaN

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to work fine. You're missing the `@keyframes` animation. Here's a codepen that seems to respond better to the keyboard http://codepen.io/anon/pen/pRpoaN

```js
if (window.addEventListener) {
  var state = 0,
    Konami = [38, 38, 40, 40, 37, 39, 37, 39, 66, 65];
  window.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == Konami[state]) state++;
    else state = 0;
    if (state == 10)
      $('#pirateship').addClass('sail');
    window.alert("test");
  }, true);
}
```

```css
#pirateship {position:absolute; top:420px;width:100%; height:160px;
background-image:url(pirateship.png); background-position:-200px;
background-repeat: no-repeat;}
.sail {animation: sailing 8s infinite linear;}
@keyframes sailing {
  100% {
    background: red;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pirateship">arr</div>
```

Comment: Actually, I found a simpler answer. That always happens, right after I post a question here. LOL

I simply had to use this:

    document.getElementById("pirateship").className = "sail";